# How to model the effect of "words occurring over time"?

Tags: modeling, graphical-model, topic-models

As time goes on, some new words may occur. But standard Latent Dirichlet Allocation assume a fixed vocabulary.  Is there some variation of the Latent Dirichlet Allocation model which can represent this phenomenon? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, thanks for your comment, I have corrected it.

Comment: I don't know if this has been done, but I see no reason why a model of this sort couldn't be derived (it would involve assuming that the underlying multinomial distribution is changing over time). However, it would introduce some tricky parameters. For example, how fast is the vocabulary growing? What is the functional form of this growth (linear, exponential, etc)? Are other words getting dropped from the vocabulary at the same rate? At different rates? How large a corpus is needed to estimate these parameters reliably? Also, when would the modified analysis beat the "naive" analysis?

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely not my field so this may well not be an answer (!), but a colleague co-authored a paper in which they used a variation of Latent Dirichlet Allocation models with the documents' mixture weight beliefs replaced with squashed Gaussian distributions [snipped from the abstract]. They use this to infer topic distribution over time.

The paper is Kernel Topic Models by Philipp Hennig, David Stern, Ralf Herbrich, and Thore Graepel in Proceedings of the Fifteenth International Conference on Artificial Intelligence and Statistics, JMLR W&CP 22: 511-519, Journal of Machine Learning Research, May 2012 with the PDF available [here](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=166607).

Here is their graph showing the change over time for the state of the union address:

[image: Hennig/Stern/Herbrich/Graepel graph]